# video recording is not working when the mobile is sleeping mode

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to do the application, when we sent the sms to a mobile , the camera will automatically on with video mode and it will start the video recording. when the mobile is not sleeping mode application working fine.but the problem is if the mobile is in sleeping mode, the  video recording is not working and it's thrown stop the execution at `mMediaRecorder.prepare();` . this the code i am using to receive the SMS:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

         pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
         wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP|PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My tag"); 
         wl.acquire();



         Thread timer = new Thread()
            { 
                public void run()
                { 
                    try { 


                        if(bundle != null)
                        {
                            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                            SmsMessage[] msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                            for(int i = 0; i <msg.length; i++)
                            {
                                msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]); 
                                incomingMsg = msg[i].getMessageBody().toString(); 
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("incomingMsg :"+incomingMsg);

                        if(incomingMsg.length() > 0 && incomingMsg.trim().contains("start") )
                        {
                            System.out.println("starting activity");
                            Intent in =new Intent(context, CameraRecorderActivity.class);
                            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(in);
                        }
                        else if(incomingMsg.length() > 0 && incomingMsg.trim().contains("stop"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("sending broadcast");
                            Intent in =new Intent(SMS_RECEIVE);
//                          in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            in.putExtra("key", "stop");
                            context.sendBroadcast(in);
                        }

                        sleep(100); 

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                            // TODO: handle exception 
                            }finally{ 
//                              wl.release(); 
                                } 
                            } 
            }; timer.start(); 


    }
```

this code i am used to record the video , // here i am getting real the problem

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create an instance of Camera.

    KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    // Create preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    int i = R.id.videoview;
    Object o = this.findViewById(i);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) o;
    preview.addView(mPreview);



    System.out.println("before run method.."+mCamera);




    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("in run method.."+mCamera);
            if (isRecording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
                isRecording = false;
            } else {
                // initialize video camera
                if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                    // now you can start recording
                     System.out.println("media recorder before start...");
                    mMediaRecorder.start();
                    System.out.println("media recorder start...");
                    // inform the user that recording has started
                    setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                    isRecording = true;
                } else {
                    // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                    // inform user
                }
            }

        }

    }, 10000);


 mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String task = intent.getExtras().getString("key");
            System.out.println("receiving broadcast :"+task);

            if(task.equals("stop"))
            {
                if (isRecording) {
//                  unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
                    // stop recording and release camera
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                    mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                    // inform the user that recording has stopped
                    setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
                    isRecording = false;


                    finish();
                } else {
                    // initialize video camera
                    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                        // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                        // now you can start recording
                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                        // inform the user that recording has started
                        setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                        isRecording = true;
                    } else {
                        // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                        // inform user
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVE));

 // Add a listener to the Capture button
    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isRecording) {
                    // stop recording and release camera
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                    mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                    // inform the user that recording has stopped
                    setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
                    isRecording = false;
                } else {
                    // initialize video camera
                    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                        // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                        // now you can start recording
                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                        // inform the user that recording has started
                        setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                        isRecording = true;
                    } else {
                        // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                        // inform user
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

public void setCaptureButtonText(String s) {
    captureButton.setText(s);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
//    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");


    File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File path = new File(rootDir.getAbsolutePath(),"/Srinivas/");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! path.exists()){
        if (! path.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(path + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(path.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".3gp");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    System.out.println("mediaFile :"+mediaFile);
    return mediaFile;
}

private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    try {
    //mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.stopPreview() ;
    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
//    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(240, 240);
    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    System.out.println("1");
    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    System.out.println("2");
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        System.out.println("3");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: dont let the device to sleep

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Camera does not work in a sleeping device. If your app wakes up on an incoming SMS, you can start the Activity, and it will turn the screen on.

For that, `Activity.onCreate()` should set the following flags:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```